# PhalconPHP - Add multiple checkboxes in form from model

Tags: php, phalcon

I have got two models: Rooms and RoomAttributes. There is a many-many relation between them:

```php
$this->hasManyToMany(
    "id",
    "RoomAttributes",
    "roomID",
    "attributesID",
    "roomattributesrelation",
    "id",
    array('alias' => 'attributes')
);
```

Now I'm creating a form to add a new room and I want to have a list of all  attributes as checkboxes. What is the best way to do this and how should I save my room model after?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing... This is what upsets me in phalcon community. A simple question like that and no answer on 5 days...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
       use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Select;

            class RoomForm extends \Phalcon\Forms\Form {
                $attr_arr = ['attr1_id' => 'attr1_name', 'N_id' => 'N_name'];
                // or $attr_arr= array_column(RoomAttributes::find()->toArray(),'id','name')

                $attributes = new Select(
                    'attributes[]', 
                    $attr_arr ,
                    ['multiple' => 'multiple'
                ]);
                $this->add($attributes);
            }
```

in controller

---

```
****
if($new_room->save()){
    $attributes = $_POST['attributes'];
    foreach ($attributes as $id){
        $new_attribute = new RoomAttributes();
        $new_attribute->roomID = $new_room->id;
        $new_attribute->attributesID = $id;
        $new_attribute->save();
    }
}
```